# Particle children "simple" stop showing on certain frame

Tags: particles

I'm simulating particles with boolean object as the emitter and icosphere as particle.

Adding simple children was fine, but when it hits a certain frame (43 to be exact), the children just gone on display and in render.

Tried several things that I thought could've been the quirk, like;

- changing numbers of particles,
- moving the boolean mesh so it won't completely disappear
- deleting cache manually

Anything I should tweak? Or is there a workaround?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Just found out, the culprit is the Boolean.
Tweak translation of intersecting objects to make it work.